# Equivalence of two different definitions for $\mu^*$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For a measure space $(X,S,\mu)$ we have:
$\mu^*(A):=\inf\bigg\{\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n)\ :\ \{A_n\}\subseteq S,\ \{A_n\} \mbox{ disjoint},\ 
A\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\bigg\}
\\ = \inf\bigg\{ \mu^*(B)\ : \ B \mbox{ is a $\sigma$-set with } A\subseteq B\bigg\} $

and I am trying to prove that the second definition is equivalent to the first.

I think I found that $$\inf\bigg\{\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n)\ :\ \{A_n\}\subseteq S,\ \{A_n\} \mbox{ disjoint},\ 
A\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\bigg\}\leq \inf\bigg\{ \mu^*(B)\ : \ B \mbox{ is a $\sigma$-set with } A\subseteq B\bigg\}$$
so that the proof could be finished by proving the converse inequality. Could someone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
Just solved this problem. Maybe some people are still trying to find a proof for the above, so
I thought I'd post my solution:

It is clear that the restrictions ($B$ is a $\sigma$-set with $A\subseteq B$) and 
($\{A_n\}\subseteq S$ disjoint with $A\subseteq\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$) are equivalent.
So we can always consider $B=\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, and it is sufficient to prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n)= \mu^*(B)$.

The set of all $\mu^*$-measureable sets, denoted by $\Lambda$, is a $\sigma$-algebra, and $S\subseteq \Lambda$. So the union we consider, $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, is a member of $\Lambda$. Using the fact that $\mu^*$ restricted to $\Lambda$ is $\sigma$-additive,
and the fact that $\mu^*$ is an extension of $\mu$, yields:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^*(A_n)=\mu^*(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=\mu^*(B),$$

which was to be proved.

Comment: Is there an star in the second definition? What do you mean by a $\sigma$ set?

Comment: There is indeed a star in the latter definition. By a $\sigma$ set I mean a set that one could write as a countable union of disjoint sets in $S$. So $B=\cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$, where $\{B_n\}\subseteq S$ is a disjoint sequence.